# $x^2+y^2-1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

To solve the Dummit-Foote's exercise I've stuck here with this problem : (P-312)

Qn11. Show that  $p(x)=x^2+y^2-1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$.

This is a polynomial of degree 2. But I can not think of zeros of this polynomial.

My another approach is : $p(x)=x^2-1\in \mathbb{Q}[x,y]/\langle y\rangle$ and also $p(x)=y^2-1\in \mathbb{Q}[x,y]/\langle x\rangle$ and $\langle x\rangle$, $\langle y\rangle$ are proper ideal of $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$. Also, $p(x)=x^2-1$ can be factored with $(x+1)(x-1)$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/\langle y\rangle$. Then how I go ahead?

I think my attempt is stupid. Can any one suggest any references to understand/solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your trying?

Comment: Do you know a powerful criterion for irreducibility for Q ?

Comment: > But I can not think of zeros of this polynomial.

Really? There are four very obvious ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the definition of irreducible element. Suppose 
$$
x^2+y^2-1 = p(x,y)\cdot q(x,y),
$$
with $p,q\in \mathbb{Q}[x,y]$, so that $2 = \deg_x p + \deg_x q$ and $2 = \deg_y p + \deg_y q$. The only case to consider is when both $p$ and $q$ are linear in $x$ and $y$. We can write them explicitely and reach a contradiction when imposing that their product must be equal to $x^2+y^2-1$.

---

An approach which is not brute force is to look at $x^2+y^2-1$ as a polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[y][x]$ and use one irreducibility criterion.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: consider $x^2+y^2-1\in\mathbb{Q}[y][x]$ and use a well-known irreducibility criterion holding over every PID.

Comment: And what is that powerful irreducibility criterion that works over any PID? I'm asking just for my own learning. And does it work over any $R[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ where $R$ is a PID?

Comment: @stressedout [Eisenstein's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein's_criterion). Only on a PID.

Comment: Thanks. The Wikipedia link doesn't discuss its generalization to PIDs, but it says something about generalizing it to $D[x]$ where $D$ is an integral domain. I hope I'm not bothering you by asking too many questions, but could you elaborate further? And the statement is for single variable polynomials. How does it apply to multivariable polynomials?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: if a polynomial $p(x,y)$ over $K$ (any field, or in fact any domain) is reducible, then either for all $k\in K$, the polynomials $p(x,k)$ are reducible or for all $k\in K$, the polynomials $p(k,y)$ are reducible. This is clearly not true for $K=\mathbf Q$ and your $p$.